# clustering or k-medians of points on a graph

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, median

I'm plotting frametimes of my application and I'd like to automatically work out medians. I think the k-medians algorithm is exactly what I'm after, but not sure how my problem applies. My data points are at **regular intervals**, so I don't have arbitrary **2D** data but I also don't have just **1D** data as the *time* dimension matters.

[image]

How should I go about computing these clusters (I'd be more than happy with just 2-medians instead of k-medians)? The data can be quite noisy, which is why I want medians instead of means, and I don't want the noise to interfere with the clustering.

Also, is there a more in-depth article than wikipedia's [K medians clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering)?

Comment: Would you *prefer* k=2 clusters or just tolerate an algorithm that only gave you two?

Comment: @Adam I would be very interested in a general solution, but I probably only need k=2.

Comment: You can try something like a segmented linear regression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression . Sorry, don't have the time to write a full answer at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use clustering.

Cluster analysis is really *designed* for multivariate data.

1 dimensional data is *fundamentally* different, because it is ordered. Multivariate data is not. This means that you can construct *much* more efficient algorithms for 1-dimensional data than for multivariate data.

Here, you want to perform *time series segmentation*. You may want to look into methods such as natural breaks optimization, but also e.g. kernel density estimation.

The simplest approach is to keep track of the standard deviation, and once a number of points deviates from this substantially, segment there.